# ERC4337 code query in solidity code

Tags: solidity, account-abstraction

```
function initialize(uint256[4] memory aPublicKey) public virtual initializer {                
    (aPublicKey);         
    super._initialize(address(0));     
}
```

What does (aPublicKey) in the 2nd line inside the function means in this function?

Comment: Likely to eliminate unused variable warning in Solidity compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line (aPublicKey); in the given function does not have any effect on the code execution or state. In fact, it's a no-op (no operation) statement.

It's possible that the developer intended to use this variable in some way but forgot to complete the implementation, or it could be leftover code from a previous version of the function that was not properly cleaned up.

Since it has no effect on the code, you can safely remove the line without impacting the function's behavior.